# JavaFX controls not receiving mouse events when also using Shape3D

Tags: java, scala, javafx, scalafx

I'm working on a ScalaFX application that has both controls and models in the same window (it is a game).  Unfortunately, when I add the models, the controls stop receiving mouse events even though the two do not overlap.  A smallest working example looks like this:

```
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene._
import scalafx.scene.control._
import scalafx.scene.input.MouseEvent
import scalafx.scene.layout._
import scalafx.scene.shape._

object GameWindow extends JFXApp {
  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    scene = new Scene(800, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.Balanced) {
      root = new VBox(
        new Button("Click me!") {
          handleEvent(MouseEvent.MouseClicked) {
            me: MouseEvent => Console println "clicked!"
          }
        },
        new Sphere() {
          radius = 100
        })
    }
  }
}
```

If I replace the sphere with a 2D shape, like `Circle` or `Rectangle`, the controls become responsive again; it is only a problem when I add 3D shapes.  I have tried setting `mouseTransparent` and clearing `pickOnBounds` on the `Sphere`, but neither seem to work.

How can I let the controls continue to receive mouse events when they are clicked?  It is acceptable for the models to not receive them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mixing 2D (controls) and 3D content you should wrap the 3D content in a `SubScene`, for instance like this:

`object GameWindow3D extends JFXApp {
  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    scene = new Scene(800, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.Balanced) {
      root = new VBox(
        new Button("Click me!") {
          handleEvent(MouseEvent.MouseClicked) {
            me: MouseEvent => Console println "clicked!"
          }
        },
        new SubScene(400, 400, true, SceneAntialiasing.Balanced) {
          root = new VBox {
            children = new Sphere() {
              radius = 100
            }
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }
}`